# Return value in sales.order.line from wizard in Odoov10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

I have a Many2many type field in wizard('pack_ids') and also a Many2many('pack_id') type field in sale.order.line. And i want that the value of Many2many type field of wizard('pack_ids') return in sale.order.line field('pack_id').

**For this my code is here:**

```
class SalePackWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "sale.pack.wizard"
    _description = "Sale Pack Wizard"

    @api.onchange('product_id')
    def _onchange_product_pack_name(self):
        print"A:", self.product_id.product_pack
        res = self.product_id.product_pack
        a = {}
        print "res:", res
        if res:
            domain = {'pack_ids': [('id', 'in', [v.id for v in res])]}
            a= res
            print "a:", a
            return {'domain': domain}

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="Product Pack", required=True, domain="[('is_pack','=',True)]")
    qty = fields.Float(string='Quantity', digits=dp.get_precision('Product Unit of Measure'), required=True, default=1.0)

    pack_ids = fields.Many2many('product.pack', string='Pack Products', change_default=True,
                               default=_onchange_product_pack_name)


    @api.multi
    def action_salepack_add(self):
        rec = self._context.get('active_ids', [])
        print "REC", rec, self.product_id.categ_id #product_uom
        if rec:
            line_values = {'product_id': self.product_id.id,
                           #'design_id':self.design_id.id,
                           'pack_id': self.product_id.product_pack,
                           'category_id':self.product_id.categ_id.id,
                           'order_id':rec[0],
                           'product_uom_qty':self.qty,
                           }
            sale_order_line = self.env['sale.order.line'].create(line_values)
```

Comment: Hi, what's this the type of field **product_pack** in the **product.product**?

Comment: It's Many2one type field

Answer (score 1):

you can update your code by that:

```
@api.multi
    def action_salepack_add(self):
        order_id = self._context.get('active_id',False)

        if order_id:
            line_values = {'product_id': self.product_id.id,
                           'pack_id': [ ( 6, 0, [self.product_id.product_pack.id] ) ],
                           'category_id':self.product_id.categ_id.id,
                           'order_id':order_id,
                           'product_uom_qty':self.qty,
                           }
            sale_order_line = self.env['sale.order.line'].create(line_values)
```

You cant create values in a many2many field just giving it the id (this is only for many2one). If the field is a one2many or many2many:

```
(0, 0, { values }) link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
(1, ID, { values }) update the linked record with id = ID (write values on it)
(2, ID) remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
(3, ID) cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
(4, ID) link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
(5) unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
(6, 0, [IDs]) replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)
```

Comment: It shows following error: "ValueError: Expected singleton: product.pack(1, 2, 10)". I also applied for loop.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed Karara...! Error fixed.

Comment: Hello Mohamed,
How to add multiple fields values in single many2many field in Odoov10?

Comment: My Question on this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763834/how-to-add-multiple-fields-values-in-single-many2many-field-in-odoov10

Answer (score 0):

Error Fixed. Here is the solution for error:

```
@api.multi
    def action_salepack_add(self):
        rec = self._context.get('active_ids', [])
        print "REC", rec, self.product_id.categ_id #product_uom
        if rec:
            line_values = {'product_id': self.product_id.id,
                           #'design_id':self.design_id.id,
                           'pack_id': [(6, 0, [v.id for v in self.product_id.product_pack])],
                           'category_id':self.product_id.categ_id.id,
                           'order_id':rec[0],
                           'product_uom_qty':self.qty,
                           }
            sale_order_line = self.env['sale.order.line'].create(line_values)
```

Thanks,